# Interpretation of the expected time of coming back to the origin for the random walk on ring.

Tags: random-walk

When one move on a ring randomly, the expected time to coming back to the origin is  equal to the perimeter according to [this](http://www2.math.uu.se/%7Esea/kurser/stokprocmn1/slumpvandring_eng.pdf).

At frist, the man is at the origin. For each second, he move left or right by 1 meter randomly. The perimeter of the ring is $n$ meter. Then the expected time of coming back to the origin is $n$ seconds which can be obtained by solving reccurence formula.

I want to know the interpretation (or feeling) of this result since the result is very simple. Is there any other simple way to get that the expected time is euqal to the perimeter.